# how to get sum of rows when a column follows same value?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sum, grouping, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like :

```
 time(secs) setup
     40     setup1
     30     setup1       
     20     setup1
     10     setup2
     20     setup2 
     10     setup1
     30     setup1
     30     setup2
     40     setup2
     10     setup3
     20     setup3
```

I would like to get sum of rows in `pandas dataframe` depending on the similar `setup` value as:

```
  time(secs)  setup
    90        setup1
    30        setup2
    40        setup1
    70        setup2
    30        setup3
```

But by using `groupby()` function :

```
  df.groupby(['setup']).sum()
```

I am getting result as:

```
  setup      time 

  setup1      130 
  setup2      100
  setup3       30
```

kindly help to resolve this issue ...

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby and aggregate `sum` with `first` by helper `Series` by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of compared by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) `(!=)`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['setup'].ne(df['setup'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
         .agg({'time(secs)':'sum', 'setup':'first'}))
print (df1)
   time(secs)   setup
0          90  setup1
1          30  setup2
2          40  setup1
3          70  setup2
4          30  setup3
```

Detail:

```
print (df['setup'].ne(df['setup'].shift()).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     5
10    5
Name: setup, dtype: int32
```

---

Similar solution with new column:

```
df['groups'] = df['setup'].ne(df['setup'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df)
    time(secs)   setup  groups
0           40  setup1       1
1           30  setup1       1
2           20  setup1       1
3           10  setup2       2
4           20  setup2       2
5           10  setup1       3
6           30  setup1       3
7           30  setup2       4
8           40  setup2       4
9           10  setup3       5
10          20  setup3       5

df1 = (df.groupby('groups')
         .agg({'time(secs)':'sum', 'setup':'first'})
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['groups', 'setup'])['time(secs)'].sum()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   time(secs)   setup
0          90  setup1
1          30  setup2
2          40  setup1
3          70  setup2
4          30  setup3
```